# ¿Cómo ordeno y muestro una tabla que tiene data de cabecera y cuerpo separados en javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, table

quiero armar una tabla con data en json, la he generado pero el orden de las celdas no coinciden con las cabeceras:

La cabecera y data vienen separadas:

```
var header = data.result.fields;
var body = data.result.items;

header = [
    {key: "region", label: "Region 1", sortable: true},
    {key: "code", label: "1", sortable: true},
    {key: "name", label: "nombre", sortable: true},
    {key: "quantity", label: "Q", sortable: true},
    {key: "nps.pr", label: "Pr", sortable: true, formatter: "valuePercent", thClass: "bg-success text-white"},
    {key: "nps.nt", label: "Nt", sortable: true, formatter: "valuePercent", thClass: "bg-warning text-white"},
    {key: "nps.dt", label: "Dt", sortable: true, formatter: "valuePercent", thClass: "bg-danger text-white"},
    {key: "nps.total", label: "NPS", sortable: true, formatter: "valuePercent", thClass: "bg-sky-blue text-white"},
    {key: "attributes.lcs", label: "LCS", sortable: true, formatter: "valuePercent", thClass: "bg-success text-white"}
    {key: "attributes.ca", label: "CA", sortable: true}
    {key: "attributes.ado", label: "ADO"}
    {key: "attributes.pb", label: "PB", sortable: true}
]

body = [
    {
        code: "2",
        region: "region I",
        name: "nombre celda",
        quantity: 23,
        attributes: {
            ado: "10",
            ca: "25",
            lcs: "85",
            pb: "89"
        },
        nps: {
            dt: "13",
            nt: "21",
            pr: "65",
            total: "52"
        }
    },
    {
        code: "2",
        region: "region I",
        name: "nombre celda",
        quantity: 23,
        attributes: {
            ado: "65",
            ca: "90",
            lcs: "81",
            pb: "95"
        },
        nps: {
            dt: "30",
            nt: "274",
            pr: "62",
            total: "58"
        }
    }
]
```

Como esté ordenada la data de "body" necesito que se muestre en el mismo orden que de la cabecera. Es decir, por ejemplo, en "header" el "key" Region está en primer lugar por lo tanto la data del "body" en "region" debe estar en la primera celda (pero el json lo muestra en el 2do lugar o en cualquier otra posición), y así las demás celdas.

Tengo generada la tabla, pero falta el orden correcto:

```
dataHead = [];
$('#table thead .row-ths').empty();
$.each(header, function (id, item) {
    dataHead[item.key] = [{
        'id': id,
        'key': item.key,
        'formatter': item.formatter ?? '',
    }];
    $('#table thead .row-ths').append(`
        <th class="`+item.thClass+`" sortable="`+item.sortable+`" key="`+item.key+`">`+item.label+`</th>
    `)
})

$('#table tbody').empty();
$.each(body, function (id, item) {
    row = '';
    $.each(item, function (itemid, itemitem) {
        if($.isPlainObject(itemitem)) {
            $.each(itemitem, function (subitemid, subitemitem) {
                var subkey = itemid+'.'+subitemid;
                if(dataHead[subkey]) {
                    var formatter = dataHead[subkey][0].formatter ? '%' : '';
                //if(jQuery.inArray(subkey, dataHead) !== -1) {
                    row += `<td data-key="`+subkey+`">`+(subitemitem+formatter)+`</td>`
                }
            })
        } else {
            if(dataHead[itemid]) {
            //if(jQuery.inArray(itemid, dataHead) !== -1) {
                row += `<td data-key="`+itemid+`">`+itemitem+`</td>`
            }
        }
    })

    $('#table tbody').append(`
        <tr>`+row+`</tr>
    `)
})
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te sugiero que hagas una función que tome los *headers* y al *array* de datos y lo devuelva todo en un array de objetos del estilo `[{ ...header, rows: [ value, value, ...] }, ...]`. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Cómo sería, es que ya he intentado varias formas pero no logro mostrarlo en el orden adecuado :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sugería en mi comentario, lo que yo haría en este caso sería "*mergear*" los dos *arrays* `header` y `body` para crear un único *array* cuyos objetos tengan la descripción de cada *header* junto con sus valores.
De este modo, puedes manipular ese *array* de la forma que quieras antes de renderizarlo.

> *Disclaimer*
> No entraré en los detalles de cómo renderizarlo. Voy a suponer que con esta respuesta será sencillo renderizar la tabla con el *array* de objetos resultado.

El objetivo es conseguir un *array* de objetos con la forma:

```
[
  { 
    "key": "region", 
    "label": "Region 1", 
    "sortable": true, 
    "rows": [ 
      "region I", 
      "region I" 
    ] 
  },
  ...
]
```

Se trata de un objeto con las mismas propiedades que un *header* pero con un nuevo atributo `rows` (el nombre es totalmente *up to you*) que contendrá el valor con la *key* del mismo valor que `key` de todos los objetos del *array* `body`.

Para eso, definimos la función `mergeDataTable` que tomará tanto el *array* de *headers* como todos los objetos a mostrar en la tabla (`data`).

```
const mergeDataTable = (headers, data) => {
  // function mergeHeader

  const merged = headers.map(mergeHeader);
  return merged;
}
```

La función `mergeHeader` tomará cada *header* del *array* y buscará los valores dentro del *array* `data` que coincidan con su `key`.

```
const mergeDataTable = (headers, data) => {
  const mergeHeader = header => {
    // Obtiene la key
    const { key } = header;
    // Value provider es una función que toma
    // un item de data y devuelve el valor de la key
    const valueProvider = getValueProviderForKey(key);

    // Saca todos los valores de data que coincidan con la key
    const rows = data.map(valueProvider);

    // Devuelve el mismo objeto header
    // junto con el atributo rows
    return {
      ...header,
      rows
    };
  }

  const merged = headers.map(mergeHeader);
  return merged;
}
```

Por último, `getValueProviderForKey` es una función que devuelve otra, `valueProvider`. `valueProvider` es la función encargada de obtener un *item* de `data` y devolver el valor que coincide con la *key* que se le pasa a `getValueProviderForKey`.

> En un escenario más sencillo, sería tan fácil como escribir
>
> ```javascript
> const rows = data.map(item => item[key]);
> ```
>
> Pero tenemos que controlar el caso de las propiedades *nested* como `attributes.ado`.
> Para ello, `valueProvider` separa el *string* `key` por puntos y va obteniendo los valores de las *sub keys*, si es que éstas no son `undefined` en el objeto *item*.

```
const getValueProviderForKey = key => {
  return item => {
    // También podría valer para que sea un poco más claro
    // e ir actualizando `current` y retornarlo
    // let current = item;

    // Obtiene las subKeys
    const subKeys = key.split('.');
    for (const k of subKeys) {
      // Actualiza el item el value de key si no es undefined
      item = !item || item[k];
    }

    return item;
  }
}
```

Dejo [aquí](https://codepen.io/VRoxa/pen/GRrNWLE) un *fiddle* con la respuesta completa.
Y, de nuevo, con el resultado de `mergeDataTable` es bastante trivial crear los elementos de una tabla ([invirtiendo `td` por `tr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071864/how-to-create-tables-from-column-data-instead-of-row-data-in-html) para hacerlo más sencillo) o incluso con `ul` y `li` con estilos.
El caso es que con el resultado puedes ordenar y modificar los valores dependiendo de tus necesidades (tanto los *headers* como las filas individualmente). Por ejemplo,

```javascript
const result = mergeDataTable(header, body);
result.sort(({ label: a }, { label: b }) => {
  // Ordena los 'label' de los header alfabéticamente
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias. Hice el invertido que mencionas y ya se muestra como debe ser. Quedó.